# R interaction plot not showing the graph

Tags: r, plot, interaction

I tried to get an interaction plot.my code is,

```
hours=c(16.5,11.8,12.3,16.6,21.4,17.3,16.9,21.0)
facA=factor(rep(c(1,2),c(4,4)))
facB=factor(rep(gl(4,2),1))
interaction.plot(facA, facB, hours)
```

And this what I got as the output.

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong with me code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried, `facB=factor(rep(gl(4,1),2))` worked.